# Is there a way to parse the data in Magmi before storing in DB

Tags: magento, magmi

Is there in Magmi a way to parse on the fly the data from a column before to save in the DB.
Just an example. Let's say I have the Images column with a list of images with a kind of "prefix". this way:

"IMG: myimage.png".
I wanna to remove all the IMG prefixes before to store in in the Magento DB.
Is this possible without digging too deep in Magmi source code ?

Some kind of sourcecode out there too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Value Replacer" plugin should do the trick without having to touch the code.

- attribute to replace : image
- new value for image :  `{{ str_replace('IMG:','',{item.image}) }}`

that's all ! , the value replacer will process value for any column of csv before magmi uses it for import.
it works for any column and accepts any PHP r-value , and can reference any column.

see [Value replacer plugin documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Value_Replacer).

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `processItemBeforeId()` function in a custom plugin to do this.

1. Create a new plugin file in **magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/removestringfromcolumn/RemoveStringFromColumn.php**
2. Then put together your plugin code:

   ```
   <?php
   class Magmi_RemoveStringFromColumn extends Magmi_GeneralImportPlugin
   {
   public function initialize($params)
   {   
   }

   public function getPluginInfo()
   {
       return array("name"=>"Remove String From Column",
                    "author"=>"Axel Norvell",
                    "version"=>"0.0.1");
   }

   // Runs before product is processed by Magmi.
   public function processItemBeforeId(&$item,$params=null)
   {   
       $this->removeStringFromItemColumn($item, 'IMG:', 'images');
   }

   /**
    * Removes a string from a column
    *
    * @param array $item
    * @param string $string
    * @param string $column
    * @return bool
    */
   public function removeStringFromItemColumn(&$item, $string, $column)
   {
       //Make sure the column exists.
       if(isset($item[$column]))
       {
           $this->log("The column $column is not defined for this item", "warn");
           return false;       
       }

       $column_value = $item[$column];
       $column_value = str_replace($string,'',$column_value); /*remove string */
       $column_value = trim($column_value); /*remove trailing spaces */

       $item[$column] = $column_value; /* Update the item's column value */

       return true;            
   }

   //Defines where the plugin options will appear in the Magmi UI.
   static public function getCategory()
   {
       return "Input Data Preprocessing";
   }

   }
   ```
3. Now go into the Magmi Configuration and enable the plugin named **Remove String From Column**
4. If needed, modify the plugin function with the correct string and column replacement values.

**How it works:**

When Magmi is running, it will call **processItemBeforeId()** in the plugin, before Magmi processes it and inserts it into the database.  At this point, you can manipulate the data being passed into Magmi.